# ¿Se puede poner un chat como "featured"?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, chat

Hace poco fedorqui reabrió la sala de chat titulada *[La tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia)*, que sirve como sala de charla general sobre el idioma español. Sin embargo, si la gente entra poco en Meta, no digamos en las salas de chat. Meta se puede promocionar con los enlaces *featured* en la página principal, pero ¿se puede hacer lo mismo con las salas de chat?

¿Sería posible poner la sala de chat de *La tertulia* como *featured* en la página principal? ¿O que salga el recuadro de actividad del chat que acabo de ver en la página de inicio de Meta también en la página de inicio del sitio principal?

---

<sub>NOTA: La palabra *[chat](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8er2fEZ)* la recoge el DLE.</sub>

Comment: Por lo que he investigado y veo en otros sitios, no. Aparece solamente en las páginas de Meta y de forma automática. Se puede pedir en [meta.se]. Lo que sí podemos hacer mientras tanto es crear una publicación aquí mismo hablando del chat y ponerla en featured al lado del _Resoures for learning Spanish_...